# K-means openmp parallelisation internal compiler error

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, k-means

I'm having troubles trying to parallelize the following function of the k-means algorithm.
The original code is this one:

```
void PointsToCentroides(int *Punts, int N, int D, int C, double *Centroides, int *PC, int *Sep){
int i, j, k, m;
int dist[C];    
for(i=0; i<C; i++)Sep[i]=0;     
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(j=0; j<C; j++){
        dist[j] = 0;
        for(k=0; k<D; k++){
            dist[j] += (Punts[i*D+k] - Centroides[j*D+k]) * (Punts[i*D+k] - Centroides[j*D+k]);
        }
    }
    m = min(dist, C);
    PC[m*N+Sep[m]] = i;
    Sep[m]+=1;
}}
```

I've tried to turn it to a parallel for with a critical segment for the last two instructions but it makes the program run much slower.
The parallel for code is the following:

```
void PointsToCentroides(int *Punts, int N, int D, int C, double *Centroides, int *PC, int *Sep){
int i, j, k;
for(i=0; i<C; i++)Sep[i]=0; 

#pragma omp parallel for shared(PC, Sep)
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    int dist[C], m;
    for(j=0; j<C; j++){
        dist[j] = 0;
        for(k=0; k<D; k++){
            dist[j] += (Punts[i*D+k] - Centroides[j*D+k]) * (Punts[i*D+k] - Centroides[j*D+k]);
        }
    }
    m = min(dist, C);

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        PC[m*N+Sep[m]] = i;
        Sep[m]+=1;
    }

}}
```

I've also tried to make a struct so each thread has its own data-set to save the different points it works with, but the compiler is giving en internal error message. The code is the following:

```
void PointsToCentroides(int *Punts, int N, int D, int C, double *Centroides, int *PC, int *Sep){
int i;

for(i=0; i<C; i++){
    Sep[i] = 0;
}

struct centroids{
    int p[N];
    int count;
};

struct kt{
    struct centroids cent[C];
} ptc[omp_get_max_threads()];

#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{
    for(i=0; i<C; i++) ptc[omp_get_thread_num()].cent[i].count = 0;
}

#pragma omp parallel for //shared(PC, Sep)
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    int dist[C], m, j, k;
    for(j=0; j<C; j++){
        dist[j] = 0;
        for(k=0; k<D; k++){
            dist[j] += (Punts[i*D+k] - Centroides[j*D+k]) * (Punts[i*D+k] - Centroides[j*D+k]);
        }
    }
    m = min(dist, C);
    //PC[m*N+Sep[m]] = i;
    //Sep[m]+=1;
    ptc[omp_get_thread_num()].cent[m].p[ptc[omp_get_thread_num()].cent[m].count]=i;
    ptc[omp_get_thread_num()].cent[m].count ++;
}

#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{
    int p = 0;
    for(i=0; i<C; i++){
        while(p<ptc[omp_get_thread_num()].cent[i].count){
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                PC[i*N+Sep[i]] = ptc[omp_get_thread_num()].cent[i].p[ptc[omp_get_thread_num()].cent[i].count];
                Sep[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

The error message that the compiler is giving is the following one:

```
user@pc:~/Descargas/HG$ gcc -O3 -g hg_k-means.c -fopenmp
hg_k-means.c: En la función ‘PointsToCentroides._omp_fn.0’:
hg_k-means.c:92:10: error interno del compilador: en emit_move_insn, en expr.c:3698
  #pragma omp parallel private(i)
          ^~~
0x75201a emit_move_insn(rtx_def*, rtx_def*)
        ../.././gcc/expr.c:3697
0x7409f3 extract_bit_field_1
        ../.././gcc/expmed.c:1748
0x7411f5 extract_bit_field(rtx_def*, unsigned long, unsigned long, int, rtx_def*, machine_mode, machine_mode, bool)
        ../.././gcc/expmed.c:1932
0x74e433 expand_expr_real_1(tree_node*, rtx_def*, machine_mode, expand_modifier, rtx_def**, bool)
        ../.././gcc/expr.c:10698
0x758f7a store_expr_with_bounds(tree_node*, rtx_def*, int, bool, bool, tree_node*)
        ../.././gcc/expr.c:5552
0x759bce expand_assignment(tree_node*, tree_node*, bool)
        ../.././gcc/expr.c:5321
0x66d1d0 expand_gimple_stmt_1
        ../.././gcc/cfgexpand.c:3639
0x66d1d0 expand_gimple_stmt
        ../.././gcc/cfgexpand.c:3737
0x66e79f expand_gimple_basic_block
        ../.././gcc/cfgexpand.c:5744
0x673906 execute
        ../.././gcc/cfgexpand.c:6357
Por favor, envíe un informe completo de errores,
con el código preprocesado si es apropiado.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
Véase <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> para instrucciones.
```

I'm a bit new to OpenMP parallelisation methods, so any help is welcomed.

Comment: An ICE (internal compiler error) shouldn't happen — but has.  As it requests, please make a bug report and capture all the information so that they can get it resolved.  How modern a version of GCC are you using?  If it isn't 7.2.x, then maybe you should try upgrading to that.  If it is 4.x, maybe they won't be interested in the bug report after all — unless it can also be reproduced in 6.x or 7.x.  You could also try reporting back to the distributors of your Linux distribution.  I've no clue what the workarounds might be.  (Oh, and the crash isn't directly your fault — it's the compiler's.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So you don't think that's a problem with my code? I'm using gcc/7.2.0, i'm unable to upgrade it, its a server from my university. Do you know any workarounds to the issue? Or another prespective to try to solve the issue?

Comment: The compiler problem may be that it didn’t spit an error in your code, or it may be complex and not a problem in your code at all.  Either way, the first step is to report the bug following the guidelines.  They’re quite stringent but sensible. That helps solve the problem in the future.  Getting you back in track may require downgrading (since upgrading isn’t an option; 7.2 is current).  Or you’ll have to modify your code to do the job just enough differently not to run into the bug.  Don’t modify your code until you’ve preserved the compiler-crashing version. Consult with the university IT.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonathanLeffler , i'll do that.